# boto3 : Create a S3 bucket with ACLs disabled

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, acl

I am trying to create a new bucket on S3 using boto3 and python. However, I want its ACLs to be disabled. I have tried the following code, but ACLs are still enabled. How can I disable ACLs using boto3?

```
s3.create_bucket(
    Bucket = BUCKET_NAME,
    CreateBucketConfiguration = {
        'LocationConstraint': REGION_NAME
    },
    ACL='private'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create_bucket SDK does not control Object Ownership.

I think that you need to indicate the `BucketOwnerEnforced` rule when calling [put_bucket_ownership_controls](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_ownership_controls), after the bucket has been created.